# How to create a error bar for each color class in R?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
       color = "supp", palette = "jco")
```

Just for reference, `ToothGrowth` is at the bottom of this question.

My code keeps giving me this plot:
[image: +/- error bars as a whole]
which is the +/- error of all the points, instead of the error bar for each "supp" that I delineated by color. I need it to print something like this: [image: +/- error bars by color group]
What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for the help.

Here is `ToothGrowth`:

```
len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2  11.5   VC  0.5
3   7.3   VC  0.5
4   5.8   VC  0.5
5   6.4   VC  0.5
6  10.0   VC  0.5
7  11.2   VC  0.5
8  11.2   VC  0.5
9   5.2   VC  0.5
10  7.0   VC  0.5
11 16.5   VC    1
12 16.5   VC    1
13 15.2   VC    1
14 17.3   VC    1
15 22.5   VC    1
16 17.3   VC    1
17 13.6   VC    1
18 14.5   VC    1
19 18.8   VC    1
20 15.5   VC    1
21 23.6   VC    2
22 18.5   VC    2
23 33.9   VC    2
24 25.5   VC    2
25 26.4   VC    2
26 32.5   VC    2
27 26.7   VC    2
28 21.5   VC    2
29 23.3   VC    2
30 29.5   VC    2
31 15.2   OJ  0.5
32 21.5   OJ  0.5
33 17.6   OJ  0.5
34  9.7   OJ  0.5
35 14.5   OJ  0.5
36 10.0   OJ  0.5
37  8.2   OJ  0.5
38  9.4   OJ  0.5
39 16.5   OJ  0.5
40  9.7   OJ  0.5
41 19.7   OJ    1
42 23.3   OJ    1
43 23.6   OJ    1
44 26.4   OJ    1
45 20.0   OJ    1
46 25.2   OJ    1
47 25.8   OJ    1
48 21.2   OJ    1
49 14.5   OJ    1
50 27.3   OJ    1
51 25.5   OJ    2
52 26.4   OJ    2
53 22.4   OJ    2
54 24.5   OJ    2
55 24.8   OJ    2
56 30.9   OJ    2
57 26.4   OJ    2
58 27.3   OJ    2
59 29.4   OJ    2
60 23.0   OJ    2
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code, and it seems not having problems, as stated also [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/79-plot-meansmedians-and-error-bars/).
However you can also try to use `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggsci)                                           # to have the blue and yellow theme
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes( x = dose, y = len, color = supp, group = supp )) +
geom_jitter()+                                           # jitter it
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean,                            # here add the summary, I suppose                                                            
               fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x),   # mean and +-sd
               fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x), 
               geom = "errorbar") +
stat_summary(fun.y= function(x) mean(x), geom="line", aes(group = supp))+
stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point") +
# here you add the line
scale_color_jco()+                                                          # here the colors
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"))    # you can customize
                                                                            # many features with ggplot
```

[image]